# how can I select non-first suggestion use keyboard in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to use vscode with out mouse,purely.When I press F1 to run some command or something else that can launch a drop-down suggestion list,it`s inconvenience to move up and down by arrow keys.So,my question is:Is there any way to set a key that can select one of the candidates immediately，like alt 1~9？

Comment: you can filter by typing to shorten the list

Comment: @rioV8 This can be an alternative choice but not the expected one to my honest.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about selecting one of the candidates immediately, but you can rebind the up and down arrow keys to something like `alt+j` and `alt+k` that's closer to the home row.

Go to keyboard shortcuts via `ctrl+,`

Then search up `workbench.action.quickOpenSelectNext`, double click the entry and type your desired keyboard combination. Repeat for `workbench.action.quickOpenSelectPrevious`.